# Invalid operations to binary expression ('float' and 'id')

Tags: objective-c

I'm getting this error

> Invalid operations to binary expression ('float' and 'id')

```
NSMutableArray *redValues = [NSMutableArray array];
NSUInteger *redValuesLength = [redValues count];    
NSMutableArray *arrayOne = [NSMutableArray array];
NSInteger j;
float diffForAverage, totalOne;
__block int counter = 0;
float average = totalOne / amount;
int amount = 1;

for (j = (counter + 25); j < (redValuesLength - 25); j++)
{
    diffForAverage = average - redValues[j + 1]; // error occurs here

    if (diffForAverage > -1 && diffForAverage < 1)
    {
        totalOne += redValues[j + 1]; // error occurs here
        amount++;
        [arrayOne addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(j - 25)]];
        counter++;
    }
}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: What type of objects are you storing in redValues NSMutableArray?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please don't retype error messages (or code) when you post a question. **Copy and paste**. Otherwise you make mistakes.  You can copy Xcode error messages out of the Issue Navigator. Default shortcut: <kbd>⌘4</kbd>.

The actual error message is

> Invalid operands to binary expression ('float' and 'id')

The problem is that `redValues` is an `NSMutableArray`, so its elements are objects (like `NSObject`), not primitive numbers (like `float` and `int`). The `id` type is “object identity”, and can refer to any Objective-C object, even those (extremely rare) objects that are not instances of `NSObject`.

You cannot add a `float` to an object reference, and you cannot store primitive numbers in an `NSMutableArray`.

You already know about the `NSNumber` wrapper object because you create one later in the code. You need to store `NSNumber` instances in `redValues`. Perhaps you already are doing that. Then when you get an `NSNumber` back out of `redValues`, you need to turn it back into a `float` to do math on it, like this:

```
diffForAverage = average - [redValues[j + 1] floatValue]; // error occurs here
```

If you declare your `NSMutableArray` like

```
NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> *redValues = [NSMutableArray array];
```

then the compiler knows that each element is an `NSNumber` and you can use the dot syntax (which some people prefer) like

```
diffForAverage = average - redValues[j + 1].floatValue; // error occurs here
```

Comment: Sorry about the incorrect error message, but thanks for figuring out the correct one. I'm just verifying your answer now and I'll accept it if it works.

Comment: +1 the first error is gone, but the second still remains. Would I use something like  [redValues [j + 1] floatValue]; to fix the error?

Comment: You would use the same solution in both cases where you want to do arithmetic with an element of `redValues`.